Does a consumer switch support pause frames?
I am using a DM9051 10/100M Ethernet controller IC plugged into a Netgear GS308EPP switch. It appears that flow control is not working: If the microcontroller controlling the DM9051 stops receiving, then the DM9051 rx buffer overflows. Reading out the DM9051's registers indicates that perhaps the Netgear doesn't support pause frames?
FCR        (MAC 0x0a) = 0x39
(tx pause enable, hd jam enable, flow control enable)

PHY_ANAR   (PHY 0x04) = 0x0441
(csma/cd, 10_fd, flow control enable)

PHY_ANLPAR (PHY 0x05) = 0xc1e1
(csma/cd, 10_hd, 10_fd, 100tx_hd, 100tx_fd, ack, next page)

This value of PHY_ANLPAR indicates that the Netgear's ability value is (0xc1e1 >> 5) & 0xff = 0x0f which does not include pause ability:

bit 0: device supports 10BASE-T
bit 1: device supports 10BASE-T in full duplex
bit 2: device supports 100BASE-TX
bit 3: device supports 100BASE-TX in full duplex
bit 4: device supports 100BASE-T4
bit 5: device supports pause frame
bit 6: device supports asymmetric pause for full duplex
bit 7: reserved

The GS308EPP is a gigabit Ethernet switch, so shouldn't it support pause?
(The DM9051 is only 10/100M and claims to support pause). Could there be something wrong in my auto-negotation setup that is preventing the GS308EPP from advertising pause support?

@jsotola The question is whether Netgear switches support pause frames. Apparently the answer is yes but not by default. Which aspect is unclear in the question as currently written?

@jsotola Title fixed.

Apparently the GS308EPP supports flow control, but not by default. Flow control is enabled on the HOME tab of the management web interface. Go to PORT STATUS, click the port you want to change, and click EDIT.
When this is done, the PHY_ANLPAR value reported to the DM9051 is 0xcde1. The ability field is (0xcde1 >> 5) & 0xff = 0x6f indicating PAUSE support. And PAUSE appears to work: the DM9051 rx buffer does not overflow when the microcontroller takes a nap.
Note that the flow control default setting appears to be independent of the link partner type. For example, I have a TP-Link on another port of the GS308EPP, and it is also coming up as flow control = off.
Given that pause frames are not enabled by default in the Netgear switch, I would think twice before relying on them in a product. Consider using another technology such as half-duplex or TCP to provide flow control.
